# Communicating from main code to multiple threads (that have sockets, if that matters)

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, queue, python-multithreading

I've been reading up on threading, sockets, and queues but still have a mental block on how this all works.  Right now I have a threaded server that accepts connections on a port and then spins off a new thread (and new, randomly assigned system port) to handle the remaining work.  What I'd like to do is from the main thread, communicate to the sub-threads and send them work to do.  here is an example of my threaded server:

```
import threading, time, socket

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,clientsocket):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.csocket = clientsocket
        print ("[+] New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port))

    def run(self):
        # Stuff happens here
        # keep alive
        while True:
            #send a keepalive to the network device
            data = 'someinfo'
            self.csocket.sendall(data)
            #receive keepalive
            data = self.csocket.recv(56)
            time.sleep(8)

while True:
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 3000
    tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    tcpsock.bind((host,port))   
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print ("\nListening for incoming connections...")
    (clientsock, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    newthread = ClientThread(ip, port, clientsock)
    newthread.start()
```

So there is a super simple example of my server that accepts incoming connections and spins off threads to keep the connections active.  What I would love to do now, is encorporate queues to allow me to send 'data' to an individual thread to be sent to the network device, and then get its response from the device.  In this way I can interact with multiple devices through their individual thread/socket all from my main code.  I just need a little help figuring out the best way to do this.

If it's a queue, how do I tell the queue which thread to talk to?

Thank you in advance!

[EDIT 1]

For sake of example, let's say these devices are simple devices that turn on a relay.  So each would connect to the main thread, get their separate threads spawned, and then just send responses to the keep alive.  At any time, I'd like to either interrupt the keep alive or just send my command after to say, turn on a relay or turn a relay off.  The device will perform the command and then respond with (confirmed, error, etc).  The main thread would receive this response from the sub-thread and then prompt for a new command or just wait while the keep-alive runs.  So I could sit at a terminal and turn relays on and off.

Comment: So you want your main thread to handle spawning new connections, but also to handle responses from the network devices? I think you're going to need two threads for that. Also, what do you want to do with the responses from the network devices?

Comment: Also, how are you deciding what data to send to each thread, and when to send it?

Comment: Ideally I'd like the main thread to handle everything but I don't mind if there is a thread to spawn other threads, and a thread to then manage the network devices. As for the responses, I'll likely display them on screen (SSH terminal), or I could store them in a list or maybe save to a file.  Frankly I haven't gotten that far yet.  What I'm trying to wrap my head around is how to send data to the spawned threads and then get data back.

Comment: Just edited the Q to add more detail.

Comment: Ok, so the program needs listen for incoming socket connections from devices, and then also listen on stdin for user input to control each connected device?

Comment: Dano - yes I think that's a good way to describe it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, you need a thread to handle user input, a thread to handle incoming device connections, and a thread to handle each connected device.

You can then create a separate `Queue` for each `ClientThread` instance to receive data from the user-input thread, and maintain a dict of all the `Queue` instances you've created. `dict` will need to be keyed on something that somehow identified the device - in the example below I'm using the `<IP>:<PORT>` of each connection as the key. So, now the user-input thread has a way to receive a request from the user, and send it off to the proper thread. The final piece is returning a response back. You can just re-use a `Queue` instance amongst all the threads to do this, assuming you want to block while you wait for a device to respond to a user-inputted request.

Here's an untested example demonstrating all that:

```
import threading
import socket
import Queue

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,clientsocket, in_q, out_q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.csocket = clientsocket
        self.in_q = in_q
        self.out_q = out_q
        self._tid = "{}:{}".format(ip, port)
        self.daemon = True # Assuming you want the client thread to shutdown when the main thread does
        print ("[+] New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port))

    def run(self):
        # Stuff happens here
        while True:
            try:
                # Wait 8 seconds for an incoming command
                cmd = self.in_q.get(timeout=8)
                self.csocket.sendall(cmd)
                data = self.csocket.recv(56)
                # Send result to main thread.
                self.out_q.put({'tid' : self._tid, 'data' : data})
            except Queue.Empty:
                # No incoming command after 8 seconds, do a keep-alive instead.
                data = 'someinfo'
                self.csocket.sendall(data)
                data = self.csocket.recv(56)

def handle_socket_connections(resp_queue):
    """ Thread for handling connections from devices. """
    while True:
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 3000
        tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        tcpsock.bind((host,port))   
        tcpsock.listen(5)
        print ("\nListening for incoming connections...")
        (clientsock, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()
        q = Queue.Queue() # Create a Queue for sending commands to this device.
        queues["{}:{}".format(ip,port)] = q
        newthread = ClientThread(ip, port, clientsock, q, resp_queue)
        newthread.start()


queues = {} # dict for managing input queues
resp_queue = Queue.Queue()  # Shared response queue
socket_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_socket_connections, args=(resp_queue,))
socket_handler.daemon = True
socket_handler.start()

# Wait for user input
while True:
    # example input format: '1.2.3.4:55 ON'
    in_data = raw_input("Enter using the format - <IP>:<Port> <cmd>")
    if in_data == "EXIT":
        break
    ip_port, cmd = in_data.split()
    try:
        queues[ip_port].put(cmd)  # Send command to the appropriate thread.
        result = resp_queue.get()  # Wait for a response.
        print("Got '{data}' from {tid}".format(**result))
    except KeyError:
        print("No conection on {}".format(ip_port))
```

Comment: This looks amazing.  I will get it working and let you know how it went!  Thank you Dano!

Comment: you cracked the code and taught me a lot.  Thank you very much!  Upvoting your answer and accepting.